# window.location.href('@Url.Action("UserDetails", "User")')

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Visual Studio 2010. Also I am using Razor and trying to develop an MVC application. I am using MVC4 and HTML5. I have following code

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" 
onclick = "window.location.href('@Url.Action("UserDetails", "User")')" />
```

Where UserDetails is my action and User is my controller. Whenever I click the button Click Me, User Details is returned. This happens properly in IE. But the same is not working for Mozilla and Chrome. an anyone suggest me on this. I went through google, and I have seen that many people faced the same issue. I tried couple of approaches given, but I could not be successful.Can you please tell where am I going wrong.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If your button's purpose is purely to redirect to another view, you should use a HTML Anchor (`a`) instead of an `input` element:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "UserDetails", "User", null, new { @class = "button" })
```

This will render as:

```
<a href="[your link here]" class="button">Click Me</a>
```

Then you can use the `button` class to style your link as you wish (ie. make it look like an input button, if that's your desire).